# MVC3 Trigger multiple functions on ActionLink OnComplete event?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How to trigger multiple function on OnComplete event in MVC3 ActionLink:

```
 OnComplete = "function() { one(); two(); }"
```

this, doesn't work for me? Any ideas ?

Comment: What is the generated Html output for the action link part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about mapping it to a function:

```
...{ OnComplete = "Completed" }...

<script>
  function Completed(){
    one();
    two();
  }
</script>
```

MVC is looking for the name of a function, not a string of code to execute.

Comment: @my functions are in differnet .js files, is loading order important or it canot be done this way?

Comment: @Ingol: Depends on how you're loading them. As long as the function exists, in a scope MVC can access, but the time the call's made, everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to execute JavaScript for the `ActionLink()` clicked, you'd do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("YourAction", null, new { onclick = "function() { one(); two(); }" })
```

But if you are really looking to execute something when the Action method is finished completing, you'd need to write your own ActionFilter:

```
public class ActionExecutionFinal : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

And you'd apply this to your Action method like so:

```
[ActionExecutionFinal]
public ActionResult YourActionMethod()
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you do like this

**View**

```
OnComplete = "a"
```

**JavaScript**

```
function a()
{
    b();
    c();
}
```

Comment: my functions are in differnet .js files, is loading order important or it canot be done this way, or do I need to make global functions of some kinde??

Comment: If your js files are loaded in the same page then they will see each other. This is why JavaScript has a lot of namespace issues. File A can have function Print and File B can have function Print.

Comment: But in the example there is no difference is function b in different file than function c & a.

Comment: thanks i solved it, function have to be global, not in document.ready, now, everything works... cheers